# How can I split a column in a table?

Tags: delimiter, dolphindb

I want to use function split to a column in a table, so that each element can be a new column.

For example, there is a column in the format of “aa, bb, cc“. How can I obtain new columns “aa“ “bb“ ”cc“?

Answer (score 0):

Since the object of split must be a scalar, you can use each\loop for a table.

Use user-defined function for expected columns.

```
def splitV(sp,k){
        return string(split(sp, " ")[k])
}
```

Apply it to a table:

```
sp = array(STRING, 0).append!("aa bb cc").append!("aa bb dd")
t = table(sp as sp)
select *, each(splitV,sp,0) as `a, each(splitV,sp,1) as `b, each(splitV,sp,2) as `c from t
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

If the format of this column is unified, you can use built-in function `substr` for vectorization.

Performance can be doubled:

```
select *, substr(sp,0,2) as `a, substr(sp,3,2) as `b, substr(sp,6,2) as `c from t
```